# Keycloak single use access token

Tags: keycloak

I have a resource server RS1 that is accessed via a REST API by an application App1. A user authorizes App1 to use its resources on RS1. In order to use RS1 services App1 has to acquire an access token from Keycloak. App1 is registered in Keycloak as a client with a client protocol openid-connect. App1 acquires the access token and is able to create resources for 90 days. When a resource is created, then that particular resource must be authorized again to complete its creation. This additional resource authorization should not change/replace an already existing access token and its permissions (the one that lasts 90 days).

One way I see it is that I could register App1 in Keycloak as a second client which acquires a short lived access token with a permission to that particular resource. In this case every application using RS1 will have two registered clients.

How do I go about it in Keycloak? Is Keycloak a right tool for that?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this "This additional resource authorization should not change/replace an already existing access token and its permissions (the one that lasts 90 days)." Do you want long lived access token?

Comment: The first access token is a long lived. It allows you to acquire a payment list and to create a payment resource which is not yet authorized. A second access token is a short lived and it allows you to authorize a specific payment, but it should not allow you to authorize any other payments.